# Disable `syncing settings` in Android when closing

Tags: android-studio

Using Android Studio version 4.1.1.

Every time when closing Android Studio, the `Syncing Settings` will pop up and do its job. But that's not what I want, is there a way to disable the auto sync? I am okay to manually sync it.

[image]